# Magento 2.4.6 Update Error With Payment Services

Tags: upgrade, magento2.4.6

I am unable to update from Magento 2.4.5p1 to Magento 2.4.6. When I run "composer update" I keep getting the following error:

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1

```
- magento/payment-services 1.2.0 requires magento/module-service-proxy 1.2.* -> satisfiable by magento/module-service-proxy[1.2.0].

- magento/payment-services 1.1.0 requires magento/module-service-proxy 1.1.* -> satisfiable by magento/module-service-proxy[1.1.0].

- magento/payment-services[1.3.0, ..., 1.3.1] require magento/module-service-proxy 1.3.* -> satisfiable by magento/module-service-proxy[1.3.0, 1.3.1].

- magento/payment-services[1.5.0, ..., 1.5.4] require magento/module-service-proxy 1.5.* -> satisfiable by magento/module-service-proxy[1.5.0, ..., 1.5.4].

- magento/payment-services[1.4.0, ..., 1.4.1] require magento/module-service-proxy 1.4.* -> satisfiable by magento/module-service-proxy[1.4.0, 1.4.1].

- magento/payment-services[1.6.0, ..., 1.6.1] require magento/module-service-proxy 1.6.* -> satisfiable by magento/module-service-proxy[1.6.0, 1.6.1].

- magento/module-service-proxy[1.1.0, ..., 1.2.0] require magento/framework >=103.0.0 <=103.0.4 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[103.0.0, ..., 103.0.4].

- magento/module-service-proxy[1.3.0, ..., 1.3.1] require magento/framework >=103.0.0 <=103.0.5 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[103.0.0, ..., 103.0.5].

- magento/module-service-proxy[1.4.0, ..., 1.6.0] require magento/framework >=103.0.0 <=103.0.5-p1 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[103.0.0, ..., 103.0.5-p1].

- magento/module-service-proxy 1.6.1 requires magento/framework >=103.0.0 <=103.0.5-p2 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[103.0.0, ..., 103.0.5-p2].

- magento/framework[103.0.4, ..., 103.0.5-p2] require symfony/console ~4.4.0 -> found symfony/console[v4.4.0, ..., v4.4.49] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^5.4).

- magento/framework[103.0.0, ..., 103.0.3-p3] require php ~7.3.0||~7.4.0 -> your php version (8.1.15) does not satisfy that requirement.

- Root composer.json requires magento/payment-services ^1.1 -> satisfiable by magento/payment-services[1.1.0, ..., 1.6.1].
```

Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: I was able to upgrade to Magento 2.4.5p2 without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Your issues are noticeable:

Steps To Reproduce:

- Please make sure you have the Composer 2 current version. For details, please check by running the command `composer -v`
- Make sure you have the latest version of PHP 8.1 or 8.2.
- Also, to make sure you have the latest version of Mariadb.
- Before upgrading please back up your composer file i.e., `cp composer.json composer.json.bak`

Follow the below process to upgrade:

- **Enable Maintenance mode**: Run the command: `php bin/magento maintenance:enable`.
- **Composer Backup**: Run the command: `cp composer.json composer.json.bak`
- Upgrade the composer Root Plugin if required. Run the command: `composer require magento/composer-root-update-plugin ~2.0 --no-update`
  `composer update`

Or Upgrade with Composer require commerce: (Install the Magento Version)

composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition 2.4.5 --no-update

- The run `composer update` to upgrade:
- **Update the Database Schema and Data**. Run the following command: `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`, `bin/magento setup:di:compile`.
- Disable the maintenance mode. Run the following command: `php bin/magento maintenance:disable`

Let me know if you have still any issues.

Answer (score 0):

**System requirements**

- PHP: 8.1 or 8.2
- MariaDB 10.6 (10.4 is still supported but not recommended)
- Composer 2.2.x
- Elasticsearch 8.x
- OpenSearch 2.x (1.x is still supported but not recommended)

**Steps to upgrade to the latest version of Magento**

**1. Activate maintenance mode**

```
bin/magento maintenance:enable
```

**2. Disable all cron jobs**

For Adobe Cloud: `./vendor/bin/ece-tools cron:disable`

For Magento Open Source: `bin/magento cron:remove`

**3. Start all message queue consumers manually**

To ensure that all messages are consumed, it is advisable to start all message queue consumers manually.

```
bin/magento cron:run --group=consumers
```

You should wait for the cron job to finish before proceeding. You can monitor the job’s progress by using a process viewer or by running the `ps aux | grep 'bin/magento queue` command repeatedly until all processes have been completed.

**4. Back up composer**

```
cp composer.json composer.json.bak
```

**5. Change packages**

```
composer remove magento/product-community-edition --no-update
```

- Sample data should be also upgraded:

Adobe Commerce:

```
composer require
magento/module-bundle-sample-data:100.4.*
magento/module-widget-sample-data:100.4.*
magento/module-theme-sample-data:100.4.*
magento/module-catalog-sample-data:100.4.*
magento/module-customer-sample-data:100.4.*
magento/module-cms-sample-data:100.4.*
magento/module-catalog-rule-sample-data:100.4.*
magento/module-sales-rule-sample-data:100.4.*
magento/module-review-sample-data:100.4.*
magento/module-tax-sample-data:100.4.*
magento/module-sales-sample-data:100.4.*
magento/module-grouped-product-sample-data:100.4.*
magento/module-downloadable-sample-data:100.4.*
magento/module-msrp-sample-data:100.4.*
magento/module-configurable-sample-data:100.4.*
magento/module-product-links-sample-data:100.4.*
magento/module-wishlist-sample-data:100.4.*
magento/module-swatches-sample-data:100.4.*
magento/sample-data-media:100.4.*
magento/module-offline-shipping-sample-data:100.4.*
magento/module-gift-card-sample-data:100.4.*
magento/module-customer-balance-sample-data:100.4.*
magento/module-target-rule-sample-data:100.4.*
magento/module-gift-registry-sample-data:100.4.*
magento/module-multiple-wishlist-sample-data:100.4.*
--no-update
```

Magento Open Source:

```
composer require magento/module-bundle-sample-data:100.4.*
magento/module-widget-sample-data:100.4.*
magento/module-theme-sample-data:100.4.*
magento/module-catalog-sample-data:100.4.*
magento/module-customer-sample-data:100.4.*
magento/module-cms-sample-data:100.4.*
magento/module-catalog-rule-sample-data:100.4.*
magento/module-sales-rule-sample-data:100.4.*
magento/module-review-sample-data:100.4.*
magento/module-tax-sample-data:100.4.*
magento/module-sales-sample-data:100.4.*
magento/module-grouped-product-sample-data:100.4.*
magento/module-downloadable-sample-data:100.4.*
magento/module-msrp-sample-data:100.4.*
magento/module-configurable-sample-data:100.4.*
magento/module-product-links-sample-data:100.4.*
magento/module-wishlist-sample-data:100.4.*
magento/module-swatches-sample-data:100.4.*
magento/sample-data-media:100.4.*
magento/module-offline-shipping-sample-data:100.4.*
--no-update
```

**6. Upgrade your instance**

You can upgrade your instance by using the following syntax for the composer require-commerce command:

```
composer require-commerce magento/<product> <version>
--no-update [--interactive-root-conflicts]
[--force-root-updates] [--help]
```

The command includes the following options:

- `<product>` (required): Specifies the package to be upgraded. For on-premises installations, the value should be either product-community-edition or product-enterprise-edition.
- `<version>` (required): Specifies the version of Adobe Commerce or Magento Open Source to upgrade to, for example, 2.4.3.
- --no-update (required): Disables automatic dependency updates.
- --interactive-root-conflicts (optional): Allows interactive viewing and updating of outdated or customized values that do not match the version being upgraded to.
- --force-root-updates (optional): Overrides all conflicting custom values with the expected Magento values.
- --help (optional): Provides usage details for the plugin. If neither --interactive-root-conflicts nor --force-root-updates is specified, the command retains the existing conflicting values and displays a warning message. You can refer to the Plugin Usage README for more information about the plugin.

**7. Update the dependencies**

```
composer update
```

**8. Then rub below commands :**

```
 bin/magento setup:upgrade

 bin/magento setup:di:compile

 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

 bin/magento indexer:reindex

 bin/magento cache:clean

 bin/magento cache:flush
```

**9. Disable maintenance mode**

```
 bin/magento maintenance:disable

 bin/magento cache:flush
```